# How to pass the value outside of the arrary while click on button in React js , React slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-slick

I have two Array of Objects given below

```js
Head: [ 
        {name: "abc", Number: "931", TypeCode: "73HB"},
        {name: "pbc", Number: "781", TypeCode: "89PH"}
      ];
Super: [ 
        {name: "hxc", Number: "123", TypeCode: "T78"},
        {name: "bbc", Number: "567", TypeCode: "09Y"},
        {name: "TUJ", Number: "091", TypeCode: "OWE"}
      ];

   <Slider>
   {
      Head.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          <h1>{item.Number}</h1>
          <h1>{item.TypeCode}</h1>
        </div>
      )
      )
    }
   </Slider>

  <Slider>
   {
      Super.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          <h1>{item.Number}</h1>
          <h1>{item.TypeCode}</h1>
        </div>
      )
      )
    }
   </Slider>

   <div>
    <button  onClick={this.clickHandler()}   />
   </div>

   this.clickHandler(TypeCode, TypeCode) {

    console.log(TypeCode, TypeCode)

   }
```

**How to pass the Head arrary typecode and super arrary type code in single shot with onClick button.**

Note: The button is out side of the both mappers. I am using react-slick carousel for this. Thanks advance.

Comment: How is `button` related to mappers? Can you publish more concrete code? This looks like very pseudo code.

Comment: there is no rel actually button is outside of the mappers. So here i need to pass both mapper values to the onClick function.

Comment: first, you shouldn't be invoking `clickHandler` in your buttons onclik event; change it to `<button  onClick={this.clickHandler}   />`

Comment: ya sure but i need to bind the type code while onClick that's why,

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for but if you just want to get an array of all the typecode in both Head and Super you can do this:

```
const typeCodes = Head.concat(Super).map(item =>  item.TypeCode )
```

Comment: thank you so much ,but i need based on active slide index. like TypeCode: "73HB" & TypeCode: "T78" is active in the react slick carousel i need those two only.